# Dispatcher.beginInvoke causes memory leak

Tags: c#, wpf

```
    void worker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        Action act = (Action)(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
            RRect r = new RRect(rnd.Next(100, 100), rnd.Next(100, 100), GetMousePosition(), PickBrush(), 1080);
            this.mainGrid.Children.Add(r);
        });

        while (true)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(act, DispatcherPriority.Input);
        }
    }
```

with background worker, I want to add a rectangle to my main grid every one second. I have to use this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke because of avoiding lock. My question is that

```
this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(act, DispatcherPriority.Input);
```

code block causes **a huge memory leak**. What's wrong with it?

**EDIT 1 :**

When I delete

```
Thread.Sleep(1000);          
RRect r = new RRect(rnd.Next(100, 100), rnd.Next(100, 100), GetMousePosition(), PickBrush(), 1080);           
this.mainGrid.Children.Add(r);
```

Nothing changes.

Comment: In what way is this causing a memory leak? You will see your memory usage going up, but that's normal because you're adding more items to your grid that'll have to stay in memory because they're still accessible.

Comment: @Kenneth I know how it is working, as long as I delete the code block above, nothing changes.

Comment: `while(true) { anything }` is bad idea. Do you want to wait until it's invoked? Use `Invoke`. `BeginInvoke` will very quickly fill up queue = OOM.

Comment: If you comment out the body of your anonymous function, `act`, do you still have a memory leak? I suspect you won't. I think you probably are leaking graphics objects - perhaps the brush returned by `PickBrush()` needs to be disposed.

Comment: It doesnt wait for BeginInvoke so the While(true) will probably add Milliions of Actions per second into the queue.

Comment: Did you try moving out `Thread.Sleep(1000)` inside `while(true)...` block instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code

```
while (true)
{
    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(act, DispatcherPriority.Input);
}
```

queues an infinite amount of work for the dispatcher to do. `BeginInvoke` will not wait for the `act` call to be completed, it will just put it in some internal list and return. Doing this basically *forever* will eat up all available memory.

Please note that this is not a memory leak. It is working as intended, you are just using it excessively.