# Strange behavior in regards to memory leak between Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync

Tags: c#, multithreading, memory-leaks, dispatcher, .net-4.8

I have observed a strange behavior in terms of memory leak between Dispatcher.BeginInvoke and Dispatcher.InovkeAsync(). A class object that gets passed to delegate inside InvokeAsync() (not as paramter) is not getting garbage collected after execution completion. But with BeginInvoke, this does not happen. Can somebody explain why that is so?

I have a WPF application that needs to display logs at runtime (say 500 logs per 1 min). I have an ObservableCollection<LogItem> object in viewmodel which is bound to Listbox as usual. Here SampleItem contains a large string value of length around 5000 (specifics of why this log is large will not explained here) and other smaller sized string properties. These SampleItem objects are injected into AddLog function via via event Handler from another Class.

```
Class SampleItem
{
  string SampleData;  // around length  5000

  // few other properties which are of standard base types such as int, string of smaller size like 10
}


Class LogItem
{
  string log;
}

Class MyClass
{

 ObservableCollection<LogItem> _logs = new ObservableCollection<LogItem>();
 public ObservableCollection<LogItem> Logs
 {
   get{ return _logs;}
 }


 public async void AddLog(SampleItem item)
 {
    await Application.Current.Dispatcher.InovkeAsync(new Action(()=>{
     
    // Process the SampleItem object here and create LogItem object and add it to collection   
       LogItem logitem = new LogItem() 
       // object contents are set based on contents of SampleItem
       If(Logs.Count>500)
       {
          Logs.Clear()
        }
       Logs.Add(logitem );
    

    }));
 }

}
```

With this implementation logs are displayed.
But the main issue here is memory is showing as increased in task manager. With Memory Profiling, it is observed that SampleItem objects are not getting garbage collected and is being held by AddLog await function which also is not released. I even commented out the region inside Dispatcher.InvokeAsync, same memory leak happens. Please note that SampleItem object is not used anywhere in the calling function where event handler is invoked. Memory leak will get reduced if I set the 'SampleData' property of SampleItem object as null at the end of delegate. But I don't think that is ideal.

When I tried with Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method as shown below, this kind of memory leak never occured either in TaskManaer or Memory Profile.

```
public void AddLog(SampleItem item)
 {
    Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
     
    // Process the SampleItem object here and create LogItem object and add it to collection   
       LogItem logitem = new LogItem() 
       // object contents are set based on contents of SampleItem
       If(Logs.Count>500)
       {
          Logs.Clear()
        }
       Logs.Add(logitem );
    

    }));
 }
```

Does anybody know why this happening?

Comment: Thank you Stefan! Corrected the typos.. I am human after all :)

Comment: Sure you are, me too :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dispatcher.beginInvoke causes memory leak](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40993751/dispatcher-begininvoke-causes-memory-leak)

Comment: Nope, that post does not involve state of a class object which gets trapped in a Dispatcher.InokeAsync especially if object contains a large data. This question is about the scope and  the garbage collection of a class object  passed to a function in which Dispatcher is called.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, Nope.. that link is completely different from this.

Comment: What does the difference in how you're calling AddLog look like? One version is async so needs to be awaited while one is not, and event handlers are as far as I remember from NET4 a bit tricky in their interaction with awaiting.